# DatePicker swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

При нажатии на какую-либо дату, данные передаются на другой экран. Все отлично работает кроме сегодняшней даты. Она выбрана по умолчанию и нажать на сегодняшнее число нельзя. Как исправить?

```
import UIKit
```

protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate {
func transferDate(_ date: String)
}

class DatePickerViewController: BackgroundVC {

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
var delegate: DatePickerViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate() as Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    
    let localeID = Locale.preferredLanguages.first
    datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: localeID!)
    
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func dateChanged(picker: UIDatePicker){
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let date = formatter.string(from: picker.date)
    delegate?.transferDate(date)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Назначьте закрытие контроллера и передачу даты не на событие `dateChanged`, а на действие кнопки Готово например в navigation bar, сейчас у Вас контроллер закрывается при любом изменении даты, что само по себе может оказаться неудобным - а что если пользователь выберет неверную дату? Тогда чтобы ее изменить, потребуется снова открыть контроллер с пикером.